# javascript read from a txt file and inject text into form

Tags: javascript

I apologize in the advance as I am a total beginner.
I have a pre-existing html form with text fields. I need to have a button that will allow me to upload a txt file (since when trying to look for answer about this, I learned javascript can't just access a file from my PC without me actively uploading it). Then I need the values from this txt file inserted into the text fields (for example, the form has: name, last name, phone etc - and the file will fill out this info).

I am going crazy trying to collect bits and pieces from other people's questions. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Before giving some suggestions, are you using any server side framework, if so what is it? Why do you want to use a text file, is this a requirement or your solution to a problem? It doesn't sound ideal to me so if you describe the problem you are solving with this maybe a better approach could be found

Comment: Well, I have glassfish installed on my machine, i create the war with intelliJ and deploy it to the server. I am not 100% sure I am answering your question.

My task is to be able to fill in the form (pre existing) with my credentials (or any other - it has to be changeable for different users with theirs) by a click of a button.

Comment: Thanks @Jareth, that brings us closer. There are many browser extensions for prefilling forms. That answers the server part, I'm still unsure why uploading a text file. Why wouldn't they be an acceptable solution? If that won't work you should skip the html form and create a new endpoint on your server which accepts such a text file and parses the details to then use them for the same action as the form submission. Maybe showing or describing some server code would be useful.

Comment: Hey LcLk, unfortunately, this is the challenge. I have to use the existing form (it is part of a test app we built, that has other functions as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on how you would like to have this handled, there are basically two options:

**File Upload and page redirect**

you could provide a file upload form to upload your textfile, redirect to the same page via form submission, handle the data on serverside (e.g. parse the file and get the values out of it) and let the server inject the values as default properties for the form file which is returned to the browser

**XMLHttpRequest File Upload**

in modern browsers, the native xhr object supports an upload property, so you could send the file via that upload property. it has to be sent to a serverside script that parses the file and returns the values in a fitting format, e.g. json (which would look like this: `{'name':'somename', 'lastName':'someothername'}`). then you have to register an eventlistener on completion of this upload (e.g. onload) and set these values on javascript side.

check this out for XMLHttpRequest upload (better solution in my opinion): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files

edit:
well, the easiest solution would be just to provide a textfield and paste the content of the file into this field, hit a button and the content is parsed. then you wouldn't rely on network traffic or even a serverside handling, but could do everything with javascript, e.g. like this:
dom:

```
<textarea id="tf"></textarea>
<button id="parse">fill form!</button>
```

js:

```
var tf = document.getElementById("tf");
document.getElementById("parse").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var formData = JSON.parse(tf.value);
    //if your textfile is in json format, the formData object now has all values
});
```

edit: from the link i posted in the comments:

```
<!-- The HTML -->
<input id="the-file" name="file" type="file">
<button id="sendfile">send</button>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('sendfile').addEventListener("click", function(){
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('the-file');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Add any event handlers here...
    xhr.open('POST', '/upload/path', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var values = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            //these are your input elements you want to fill!
            formNameInput.setAttribute('value', values.name);
            formFirstNameInput.setAttribute('value', values.firstName);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(formData);
});
```

as already said, your serverside has to parse the file and respond with json

Comment: Your second suggestion sounds exactly like what I was looking for! I am not sure yet if I know how to make it work (as I said..a beginner), but it gives me a good place to start. thanks!

Comment: here's a pretty good explanation on how to use the xhr upload object: https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata/

Comment: you can also check this link for an implementation of uploaded file handling on glassfish: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets016.htm

Comment: I understand that the input=file allows me to upload the file, but the major issue is how to get the information inside it to be added to the text fields inside the form. (sorry for being a bit dense, it's the first time im doing something like this)

Comment: thanks so much! it will probably take me a month to make it work inside the existing code i have, but it's a great place to start!

Comment: if it is answered to you, would be nice if you could accept it as an answer for your question :)